# Is there a way to style paragraphs after retrieving from Database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, postgresql, paragraph

I am currently working on an e-commerce website applications. I want to store product descriptions - which are long paragraphs, to the database. After that, i also need to retrieve them from the API and style the descriptions like changing the color of headings, resizing texts, line breaks, etc.

I used ReactJS, and NodeJS.

I was thinking of storing the whole paragraph with HTML tags so that when the data is fetched, the browser would parse the tags in to the DOM tree.

Comment: Product descriptions - which are long paragraphs - can be characterized as _content_ while  the color of headings, resizing texts, line breaks, etc. - as _presentation_. It is a very bad idea to mix these and store markup (i.e. presentation in this case) in the database, better do not do it. You may have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_content_and_presentation).

Answer (score 0):

You should never store HTML directly in the Database.

Even more, in React you should never write HTML content directly into your page (i.e. using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml))

HTML is just too easy to "hack" (e.g. write `<script>alert('hacked')</script>` into your data base, or somewhere into the data flow).

If you need some styling, you still probably never need all the styling features that e.g. CSS would provide.

You should carefully define a markup syntax (e.g. a subset of [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)), with only the features you really need.

E.g. only paragraphs and lists:

```js
const data = 'This product is described here.\n\nThe main features are:\n* Easy to use\n*CHEAP!'
```

Then you would sanitize and parse the data from the data base, build a local representation of the data, and build a React component that renders this specific data structure.

```
const lines = data.split('\n');
const elements = lines.map( line => createTagAccordingToMarkup( line ) );
```

There are probably libraries that can do things like that, but I don't know any. But also I guess such libraries probably tend to include more features than you need.